# Sumproduct to compare two tables to get a value within a matrix

Tags: excel-formula

I'd like to start by saying i have done alot of research on SO and google, but still coming up with nothing.

I am comparing table A within a matrix of rules in table B to find out the entitlement value the employee should get
The layout of my information is in 2 sheets

sheet A:
[image]

sheet B - the matrix:
[image]

**My formula:**
=SUMPRODUCT((sheetA!$B$2:$B$10=sheetB!$A$2:$A$10), (sheetA!$C$2:$C$10=sheetB!$B$2:$B$10), (sheetA!$D$2:$D$10>=sheetB!$D$2:$D$10), (sheetA!$D$2:$D$10<=sheetB!$E$2:$E$10), sheetB!E2:E10)

I am ending up with a 0 as the default entitlement which is incorrect because all rules are unique and I should end up with what the entitlement should be. Help is appreciated!

Comment: Is it not better to use something like `INDEX(MATCH(1,(your_condition1)*(your_condition2)*(etc.),0))`

Comment: @P.b would it be possible to give me the index match formula to get the default entitlement? I an unsure how to implement your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `SheetA` cell `E2` use `=INDEX(SheetB!E2:E10,MATCH(1,(B2=SheetB!A2:A10)*(C2=SheetB!B2:B10)*(D2>=SheetB!C2:C10)*(D2<=SheetB!D2:D10),0))`
You may need to enter the formula with `control` + `shift` + `enter`
It looks for the conditions to be true (1) in an array.
[image: SheetB]

[image: SheetA]

Comment: Enter with `ctrl + shift + enter` as this is an array function. Also check if the values in column D SheetB are numbers or text. Maybe your version of excel expects a `,` instead of `.`

Comment: See pictures in answer